# Correct "correlated" voltage tuning for (multiple) LED

Tags: led, potentiometer, led-strip, led-driver

I need to tune the voltage between 6 LED drivers ([Meanwell hlg-320h-36ab](https://www.meanwell.fr/ac-dc-single-output-led-driver-mix-mode-cv-cc-with-hlg--320h--36ab)) that delivers 36Vdc and a [LED that can take 30-41Vdc 250w for each of its 6 strips (total 1500w)](https://store.yujiintl.com/collections/led-cobs/products/yujileds-bc-series-high-cri-cob-led-900h-1500w-pack-1pc). This will change the color temperature of the light produced.

I would like to be able to tune this current as many times (say 20-200x per day) per day, ideally from with a remote, if not with a wheel; at least not with the need of screwdrivers.

What is the proper way to adjust in parallel (ie., to the same value at the same time) the tension for the 6 currents in those circumstances ?

Comment: The correct way to do color adjustments is to hook up an electrical interface and then use a digital controller to make the changes.  Typically this will be over DALI, 0-10V or PWM output to tell each driver how much current to deliver.

Comment: @user1850479 The current is not changed, but voltage. By changing tension. I'll change the color temperature (a bit), while keeping the light flux.

Comment: Those are current drivers; you're controlling the current which is adjusted by changing voltage. You cannot change voltage across a diode without driving (substantially) more/less current through it. Not sure what "tension" is?

Comment: Are these LED strips of your supposed to be driven with a constant voltage or a constant current?  Can you share a link to these LED strips?

Comment: @brhans I added a link. They are constant voltage.

Comment: @user1850479 By tension I meant voltage. So, if I have already have a 1-10V dimming, you advise against changing voltage too, because it may damage the LED or because it will also affect the luminous flux ?

Comment: Where do you get the idea that adjusting the voltage will change the CCT of that LED in any predictable fashion? And what gives you the idea that it requires a constant-voltage? This is not how that giant LED works at all...

Comment: @brhans It's (voltage-CCT) in the datasheet. But please, be my guest, enlighten me.

Comment: You can't control both voltage & current independently to a fixed load. You pick one, and the load determines the other. Your driver will apply a constant current, and the LED produces light with brightness dependent on the current. The voltage required to drive that current though the LED will depend on the internal characteristics of the LED like impurities in the material etc. and varies from batch to batch. The CCT of the LED's light output is not in any meaningful way determined by the current flowing through the LED or voltage across it (assuming it's within normal operating parameters).

Comment: LED fixtures with tunable CCT achieve that functionality by having 2 (or more) different LED types in the same fixture and varying the proportion of current between the different LEDs. So some of the LEDs will be of the 'warm' white type while others will be of the 'cool' white type. You don't get tunable CCT out of a single LED. And please feel free to enlighten me - where do you see a voltage-CCT relationship in the datasheet?

Comment: All you can control is the current.  Voltage will be adjusted automatically by your driver.  The color temperature of each individual diode will not change, but you can change the overall color temperature if you combine multiple diodes of different temperatures into your array and then dim some and brighten others.  By the way, that diode is over $1000, at least read the datasheet before you spend that kind of money!

Comment: @brhans Page 4/9 (as printed) or page 5 (PDF) of the datasheet gives CCT vs forward voltage.

Comment: @user1850479 So, do you say I should keep the 36Vdc LED driver as it is and only dimm the led with the 1-10V command, and not care about voltage and color temperature adjustment ?

Comment: No it doesn't. each of those parameters is simply expressing the limits for that particular parameter - there is no relationship between the parameters on different lines of that table. The only thing you can do with that LED is dim it by adjusting the current flowing though it. You have no direct control over the voltage, and the CCT depends entirely on which 'bin version' (56L or 56R) you buy. I'm really not making this up out of thin air - I work for one of North America's largest lighting manufacturers. Creating controls for LED lighting literally *is* my day job...

Comment: @brhans Well this makes sense. Also +/-300k is not very much, and almost undistinguishable with bare eyes.

Comment: @Soleil -- How essential is it to control the color temperature?  Is this also for imaging purposes, as in an earlier post by you?  How are you cooling this?  Most people don't know this, but much greater efficiency (Lumens per Watt) can be achieved by running at significantly lower current than the rating.  Or do you actually need 120,000 Lumens? (A movie set, or interesting photography effect is my speculation). You have me curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you've asked a few related questions about LED drivers, so I'll try and give a big picture answer.

You put current through LEDs and photons are generated at some rate, roughly 1 photon per 1.5-3 electrons.  To move that current you apply some voltage, with small changes in voltage leading to very large changes in current.  Unfortunately, the specific voltage required for a current varies from device to device, and significantly for each device as it heats up as discussed in your previous question.  For this reason we say that LEDs are current-driven devices, and we previously talked about why this means you need an LED driver and cannot just use a constant voltage source.

Now to your specific points:

> They are constant voltage.

Lets look at the datasheet:

[image: datasheet]

See how they specify a constant current and a range of voltages?  That means it is a constant current LED.  However, you don't even need to look at the datasheet to know that.  A constant voltage light means that there is some kind of current regulation or power supply integrated into the light, and there is clearly no such thing in the picture.  It is just an LED and thus constant current.

Furthermore, constant voltage devices are usually very cheap, very low power devices like holiday lights and things you can buy for a few dollars on Ebay.  They are things that are drawing a few watts.  That is a kilowatt class COB selling for over $1000. Odds are it will be constant current because the power supply required to make that constant voltage will be huge and very expensive.

> I need to tune the voltage between 6 LED drivers (Meanwell hlg-320h-36ab) that delivers 36Vdc

Lets look at your datasheet again:

[image: driver datasheet]

So that is a constant current driver outputting 8.9A with a voltage between 18 and 36V.  Immediately you should realize that this is a problem, since like we discussed in your last question you need a driver whose voltage range spans the range of your diode, whereas this driver does not.  In addition, 48A divided into 6 channels means 8 amps per channel (I'm taking your word for this, there is nothing in the datasheet indicating that the LED is wired like you suggest), so you'd also be overdriving the LED.  Since that driver has too low of a voltage and too high of a current, you should instead pick the -42 model, which can drive 21 to 42V, which spans your 30-42v range nicely.

> This will change the color temperature of the light produced.

That is a fixed color temperature LED (5600K) so all you can change is the brightness, and you can do that by lowering the current.  If you want to change the color temperature, buy two different LEDs, one higher and the other lower temperature and change the ratio of one to the other.

> What is the proper way to adjust in parallel (ie., to the same value at the same time) the tension for the 6 currents in those circumstances ?

Looking at the datasheet again:

[image: dimming]

So yes, there are a couple ways to do this.  You can use voltage control on a 1-10V scale or PWM.  The 1-10V scale is typically used by dedicated lighting controllers, while the PWM is meant to be easy to use from simple microcontrollers like an Arduino.  In either case, you can generate one of those signals from a central controller or PC which will raise and lower all of the lights.  If you do go for color temperature control, you can also program in color temperature by adjusting the ratio of the individual driver currents.

> The current is not changed, but voltage.

You cannot change voltage without also changing current.  In this case, all you can directly control is current.  Your driver has a control loop which gradually ramps up voltage, checks current and then adjusts voltage to control the current.  We discussed why in your previous question, but the reason for this is the NTC of the LEDs.  If you try to control their brightness by voltage it is very easy to enter thermal runaway and blow up your 1000 dollar COB or burn your house down.  The control loop on your driver compensates for this; as the NTC kicks in and the voltage required decreases, the driver notes the increase in current and drops the voltage to compensate.  This is ABSOLUTELY CRITICAL with a kilowatt class light!  It will heat up so fast that without current control, you'll enter thermal runaway very easily and damage your equipment or worse.

Comment: Many thanks for the extensive details and explanation. Can you please expand the NTC acronym ?

Comment: @Soleil Negative temperature coefficient. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/584115/how-to-drive-a-led-120-126v-1500w-from-230v-or-12-24v

Comment: I think that the 42Vdc driver is not good because 42Vdc is out if the range 30-41Vdc, and the current is too low, hence the driver I selected is much better, and I checked with Meanwell that the 36Vdc is constant and stable, even with dimming, hence the range is not "relevant". The current of 8.9A from the driver is not a problem, 8A at most will be consummed by the LED.

Comment: @Soleil No, that is not correct. The driver regulates the current consumed by the LED (see above). You must give it the correct current or it will be damaged.